# big-scale tracker alternative for server filesystems

Tags: filesystems, file-search, indexing

I'm using 8tb RAID storage (XFS filesystem) filled witch lots of files. By default Suse had installed tracker for file indexing/searching but:

1. It's constantly reading HDDs (like for half a year now and it *always* takes ~90% I/O) and making the OS sluggish.
2. It simply doesn't work - it found 96 videos when I have a few thousand and 80k pictures when I have few single directories with > 500k in each + many smaller ones. When I'm looking at its statistics I feel as if it scanned just few gb.

Is there any better alternative? I'm mostly concerned with command-line search as many of these directories can't be even displayed properly by KDE (KDE apps throw file protocol error after opening >500k directories)

Comment: I don't really care about its database size, one more HDD is not big deal

Comment: I'd be best to just start it and let it index all files for few days using 100% I/O for possibly quick initial scan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard command-line, indexed file search is `locate`.  The index can be updated with `updatedb`.  Most Linux systems have these tools configured by default (where `updatedb` is set up as a nightly cron job).

The index only stores file paths.  It doesn't do any advanced indexing like file type, modified date, etc. but for many simple purposes it is sufficient.